# Why do we use klenow fragment in pyrosequencing?

Tags: dna-sequencing, sequence-analysis, polymerase

Why do we use klenow fragment in pyrosequencing instead of polymerase

Comment: The Klenow fragment is a polymerase. Are you asking why the fragment is used instead of the full polymerase?

Comment: Yes exactly right